# Touchabe Opacity doest work in React Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, touchableopacity

i am using `RN` version `0.59.9` and `React Navigaton` `3.11.1`.

I want to add onPress on my view so i wrap it in TouchableOpacity but it doest work for me.

I try to use it outside React Navigation and it is still working, so maybe it is a bug in this lib.

I have tried to set the height for the view i want to add OnPress but still not working

UPDATE:
For more info for you guys, there are some code:

i have two screens like this:

```
class VuaTraiCayApp extends Component {
      render() {
        return <AppContainer />;
      }
    }

    const stack = createStackNavigator(
      {
        Home: {
          screen: HomeScreen
        },
        Detail: {
          screen: DetailScreen
        }
      },
      {
        defaultNavigationOptions: {
          headerTitle: "Trang chủ"
        }
      }
    );

    const AppContainer = createAppContainer(stack);
```

In the HomeScreen, i want to add onPress on the view, so i wrapped the view inside TouchabeOpacity. It not works:

```
<TouchableOpacity 
      onPress={()=> {
        alert("Clicked");
      }}
    >
      <View 
        style={{
          width: 200,
          height: 500,
          backgroundColor: "pink"
        }} 
      />
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

But if i use the same code outside the stack. Let's see i move this code go to the root without in stack. It works perfectly.

```
class VuaTraiCayApp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
       <TouchableOpacity 
          onPress={()=> {
            alert("Clicked");
          }}
        >
          <View 
            style={{
              width: 200,
              height: 500,
              backgroundColor: "pink"
            }} 
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes VSCode import Touchable from gesture handler

```
import {
 TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native-gesture-handler'
```

You need to link the library properly, Otherwise it will show the button, but click mayn't work. (This is just an edge case i encountered)

Other helpful links: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1225

Comment: Thanks, it is my mistake. It has been added from ' gesture handler '. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

here's my implement base on your original code. It's work fine. Please you it to compare with your. Or for sure, post your HomeScreen. I think I can figure out.

If you want to test it. Copy all of mine and paste it into your App.js ( make sure the root index.js is suitable with new one )

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { createAppContainer, createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation'
import { TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native'

class HomeScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          alert("Clicked");
        }}
      >
        <View
          style={{
            width: 200,
            height: 500,
            backgroundColor: "pink"
          }}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }
}

class DetailScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          width: 200,
          height: 500,
          backgroundColor: "yellow"
        }}
      />
    )
  }
}

const stack = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen
  },
  Detail: {
    screen: DetailScreen
  }
}, {
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      headerTitle: "Trang chủ"
    }
  })

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(stack);

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <AppContainer />
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Your code works fine. I know the problem now, VS Code imports TouchableOpacity from ' gesture handler '. I changed it and it works now. Thanks for your help.